# Why are man made substances in the periodic table?

Tags: elements

Why are man made substances such as Berkelium and Lawrencium in the periodic table if they aren't natural substances? I thought the periodic table was suppose to have elements on it, which are the purest substances in the known world? And all the natural elements have use, but some of the man made ones do not even have uses because they can't make enough of it to be useful? The whole thing just confuses me.

Comment: If a substance is man-made it doesn't mean the substance isn't pure.

Comment: The periodic table of elements does not list elements out of purity or out of natural existence. It lists them according to their atomic number (as well as their electronic structure). If you can put in one extra proton and thus increase the atomic number to something new, then that is a new element. Regardless of its use or anything else.

Comment: Why are enormous numbers like $10^{{10}^{10}}$ included in the natural number system if nobody has ever found a use for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using a meaning of "pure" that is different from the way scientists are thinking about it when they put together the table.

Elements are defined as atoms which have a set number of protons in each nucleus.  Oxygen atoms *always* have 8 protons in each nucleus.  Sulfur atoms *always* have 16.  Lawrencium atoms *always* have 103.

Elements are important in this way because it is monumentally difficult to change the number of protons in an atom.  Breaking apart the hydrogen and oxygens of a water *molecule* takes 142 MJ/kg (Point of reference, 1 MJ is roughly a snicker's bar worth of energy, so it takes the energy in 142 snickers bars to break the bonds of 1kg of water).  That was a molecular operation -- the elements (hydrogen and oxygen) remain hydrogens and oxygens.  Now consider fusing those hydrogens into helium.  That means taking two atoms that each have 1 proton, and mushing them together into a single atom with 2 protons.  This is changing 1 element into another.  That will take 135,080 MJ/kg, or about 1/10th of a standard freight container full of snickers bars!

(If you think in terms of explosives, that's about 32 tons of TNT!)

So if nothing else, we must admit that there is a *very* large difference between chemical reactions which occur on the molecular scale and nuclear reactions which occur on the atomic (element) scale.

So all that being said, why is the atomic table important?  Why have everything on it, even man made atoms?  The big selling feature of the atomic table is that it is remarkably good for predicting chemical behaviors.  You can figure out quite a bit about how an atom will interact with others based on where it is in the chart.  This holds true for both natural and man made elements.

In fact, this is actually where it came from.  The periodic table was actually first developed before we knew the atomic number for all these atoms.  There had been many tables, but [Mendeleev's table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table#History) is the one that's in the basic format we are used to today.  He had grouped them by reactivity, and had left gaps where it seemed like there should be additional elements that had not yet been discovered.  It wasn't until almost a generation later that Henery Mosely and others realized that this ordering by reactivity was *also* an ordering by atomic number.

This is, of course, a natural consequence.  The atomic number states how many protons there are in a nucleus.  Thus it also states how many electrons there are when the atom is neutral.  As we find out later, the number of electrons is the dominating factor in how elements react with one another.  So if you order things by atomic number, you also order them by reactivity -- and vice versa!

Over time, we discovered all of the "natural elements," and put them into the holes on Menedleev's table.  But the story didn't end there.  With modern technology, we could finally generate that massive amount of energy required to smash large atoms together and fuse them into even larger atoms!  Some of these elements are fleeting, as you pointed out, but they lasted long enough to generate key signatures that the scientists could use to show that the atom they created did indeed have the properties desired.  It's like when a skilled mechanic turns a car on and hears one fleeting "klunk" noise, and that's all it took for him to know that one of the spark plugs isn't firing right!

So since the patterns Mendeleev set up continue to work as expected, we simply kept adding to the table.  There was no reason not to.

And sometimes the line between natural and synthetic can be a bit blurry.  [Technetium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technetium#History) is probably one of the more poignant examples.  Mendeleev's table had a gap where element number 43 should go.  We had never seen it in nature, but his table suggested there *should* be an element with properties related to its row and column in the table.  Technetium was officially discovered in 1937, when it was produced synthetically, ~60 years after Mendeleev predicted it should exist!  So it became the first synthetic element to be put into the atomic table, filling a gap between the natural elements of molybdenum and ruthenium.

In 1952, however, astronomers noticed the telltale signature of Technetium in the burning heart of S-type red giants.  So at that point, we had to admit that our synthetic element was indeed natural, just nobody had seen it before we created it artificially!  (We now know that Technetium occurs naturally in the earth's crust at a rate of about 0.003 parts per *trillion*)

So it's not about being natural.  It's about completeness, and a pattern started in the 1800s which has continued to successfully predict the reactivity of elements all the way through up to today!

Answer (score 2):

The periodic table expresses the rules of electronic shell structure in a comprehensive way. In doing so it is so accurate that it clearly indicates the presence of elements that hadn't yet been discovered at the time the chart was put together, and allowed chemists to predict their properties before the search for them had even begun.

Some of those "missing" elements were found in nature but others were not; these were then synthesized in laboratories using particle accelerators.

An element's presence in the table doesn't depend on whether or not it is natural or useful or rare.

Artificially-created elements are not necessarily useless. Plutonium, for example, does not occur naturally but is the main ingredient in atomic weapons.

When putting together a periodic table, the customary thing is to tint the squares in which the artificial elements reside a different color than their naturally-occurring neighbors.

Comment: And, what naturally occurs here on Earth has little to do with what naturally occurs during a supernova, where one might suppose any number of unstable elements and isotopes occur for a brief time.

Comment: Yep yep. My answer scratches the surface...-NN